# Storing Date and compare it

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsdate

in My application I require that each time I start app to check date and compare it with date when I last start app. The difference between the date must be last 14 days.

**Example:**

Last date 20.8.2015

Current date: 26.8.2015

compare this two dates and if the difference is less than or equal to 14 days print "last 14 days".

My code:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
       NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
       [dateformate setDateFormat: @"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
       NSString *date = [dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

       //TO STORE DATE
       NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       [defaults setObject:date forKey:@"Date"];
       [defaults synchronize];
    }
```

Comment: I need to compare current date with date when I last open my app in range 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
  NSString *nowDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

  if ( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Date"] ) {
      NSUserDefaults *defaults          = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      NSDate         *capturedStartDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[defaults objectForKey:@"Date"]];

      NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
      NSDate *endDate   = capturedStartDate;

      NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [startDate timeIntervalSinceDate:endDate];
      int            numberOfDays   = (int) ( secondsBetween / 86400 );
      if ( numberOfDays >= 14 ) {

          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nowDate forKey:@"Date"];
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
      }

  } else {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nowDate forKey:@"Date"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
           NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
           [dateformate setDateFormat: @"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
           NSString *date = [dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

           //TO STORE DATE
           NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
           [defaults setObject:date forKey:@"Date"];
           [defaults synchronize];

          int daysDifference = daysBetweenDate:yourPreviousOpenDate andDate:todayDate

        if(daysDifference > 14{
        //your logic

}

- (int)daysBetweenDate:(NSDate*)fromDateTime andDate:(NSDate*)toDateTime
{
    NSDate *fromDate;
    NSDate *toDate;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay startDate:&fromDate
        interval:NULL forDate:fromDateTime];
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay startDate:&toDate
        interval:NULL forDate:toDateTime];

    NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
        fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

    return [difference day];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*All code typed directly into answer, expect minor errors and treat as pseudo code*

First `NSDate` values can be stored directly in user defaults, and that is far better than converting them back and forth between string representations. So to store you date all you need is:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:now forKey:@"Date"];
```

Before you do this you should retrieve the previous value:

```
NSDate *lastRun = [defaults objectForKey:@"Date"];
```

If this returns `nil` then there was no last run, this is the first run.

If this is not `nil` then use the method `timeIntervalSinceDate:` to find the `NSTimeInterval` between the two dates, this is a value in seconds. Compare that to 14 days, in seconds, and you're done...

*Unless* you want to account for calendars where days are not 24 hours of 60 mins, etc. - i.e. You wish to be absolutely precise - in which case you'll need to use `NSCalendar` to calculate the difference in days. However for many cases this is just unnecessary.

HTH